# Typescript stacked interfaces

Tags: typescript

Does Typescript have the concept of subset interfaces.

There is a parent interface `parent` which looks like:

```
interface parent {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
}
```

There are other interfaces `one` and `two`.

```
interface one {
    a: string
}
```

```
interface two {
    b: string
}
```

Both `one` and `two` shouldn't be able to add fields that aren't present in the parent interface. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Both one and two shouldn't be able to add fields that aren't present in the parent interface.

This is somewhat counter to TypeScript's structural typing philosophy, but see `NoExtraProperties` at https://gist.github.com/greglockwood/1610ef83d0726e0e6c021d46cb573e68 if you really need this functionality.

The gist was sourced from [Is it possible to restrict typescript object to contain only properties defined by its class ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined) which might also be helpful for additional context.