# Why doesn't TypeScript show an error when assigning an object with exceeding properties to a variable?

Tags: typescript

When assigning a value to a data structure, the TypeScript engine checks that it has the correct type.

```
let e = '5'

const a: number = '5'
const b: number = e
```

tsc shows 2 errors, saying `a` and `b` are both assigned a value that does not match their type.

However when using an interface as the type, tsc does not show an error if the value assigned is taken from another data structure and contains exceeding properties:

```
interface model {
  prop: number;
}

const tooManyProps = { prop: 1, prop2: 5 }
const notEnoughProps = {}

const a: model = tooManyProps
const b: model = notEnoughProps
const c: model = { prop: 1, prop2: 5 }
```

tsc shows an error for `b` and `c`, but not for `a`, while I expect it to.

Why don't I receive any error when assigning `a` an object with too many props?

Comment: This is because Typescript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) as opposed to nominal typing.

Comment: Strongly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/49580725/8186898

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript uses the structural (or duck) typing paradigm for type checking. For example, we can assign object A to object B, if B has all required properties of object A (even though B may have other properties which do not belong to A).

When we generate an object and assign it to a variable we can pass it to any component (a function, class, module) without a problem as long as this object has all the properties which that component expects. So, if a component gets an object which has all the properties it expects, TypeScript is happy; it doesn't check excess properties when we pass an object using a variable.

However, when we're creating an object, like in this example:

```js
interface model {
  prop: number;
}

const c: model = { prop: 1, prop2: 5 }
```

In this case, TypeScript is checking the excess properties, because usually when we're creating an object of a given type explicitly (using an object literal) we'd like to avoid extra properties. Otherwise, we could explicitly say that the "model" type may have extra properties using an index signature, like this:

```js
interface model {
  prop: number;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

So, hope this helps.

The related topics are "structural typing" and "excess property checks". You can google them for even more information.

Comment: Your snippet don't work, stack overflow doesn't support TS natively, however you can build [typescript playground links](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Answer (score 3):

Typescript allows for extra properties. So `a: model = tooManyProps` isn't a type error because `a` will "work" as a `model`. `c: model = { prop: 1, prop2: 5 }` doesn't work because Typescript doesn't allow for extra properties *in object literals*. That's definitely a Typescript caveat, but that is by design.

Answer (score 3):

There is significant difference between your examples. Where your first consider assignment values which are in types having no relation between each other. What I mean by relation is intersection, so values which are members of both types. There is no value which is `string` and `number` in the same time. It can be only `string` or `number`, that is why you cannot assign member of type `string` to the place where `number` is expected.

For Product types (products are for example js objects which are ts records) we have different story, as one type can contain all fields which are also in another type.

```
type SmallerT = {
  a: string
}
type BiggerT = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}
```

`BiggerT` is a superset of `SmallerT`, in any place `SmallerT` is required `BiggerT` can be used instead. In more interface notion we can say `BiggetT` implements `SmallerT` or extends `SmallerT`.

Such behavior is crucial for TS, as all types/interfaces are only aliases for product and union types, that means that one type with the same structure is really the same thing as another. Its [structural typying](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

```
type A = { a: string }
type B = { a: string }
```

Type `A` and `B` are equal, are the same, we can use `A` where `B` is required and another way around.

Lets go to the previous example, and write it differently:

```
interface SmallerT {
  a: string
}
interface BiggerT extends SmallerT {
  b: string
}
```

Above declaration of types is equal the previous one, we just used `extend` in order to join both types, but structurally nothing has changed, still `BiggerT` can be assigned where `SmallerT` is needed.

Consider below tree type definition equal:

```
type SmallerT = {
  a: string
}
type BiggerT = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}

interface SmallerT {
  a: string
}
interface BiggerT extends SmallerT {
  b: string
}

type SmallerT = {
  a: string
}
type BiggerT = SmallerT & {
  b: string
}
```

Type `BiggerT` contain `SmallerT` and can be used instead of it, it passes all requirements of `SmallerT`.

We can also ask TS, if our `BiggerT` can be assign for `SmallerT`:

```
type IsBiggerTAssignableToSmallerT = BiggerT extends SmallerT ? true : false
// evaluates into true for any of definitions presented above

type IsNumberAssignableToString = number extends string ? true : false
// evaluates to false as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript lint doesn't show any errors when assigning too many props to the interface because of the definition of an interface in TypeScript says that *the compiler only checks that **at least** the ones required are present and match the types required*.
So, you'll see an error when trying to pass something that doesn`t match your **prop** parameter, but not when you try to pass a **prop** and a **prop2**.

Hope it helps you.

You can find more details here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html