# Typescript, check if request body has type User otherwise throw error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, types

I'm stuck trying to solve a problem. I'm using express js to build a rest api. I want the user to be able to update their profile.

I've created a User model:

```
export type User = {
    email: string
    creation_date: number
    first_name?: string
    last_name?: string
    payment_detals?: {
        iban: string
        last_updated: string
    }
    address?: {
        city: string
        street: string
        house_number: string
        postal_code: string
    }
    products?: string[]
}
```

But I want to receive the request body and update the value for that user in the database (No SQL, Firebase). But I don't want the user to add fields which are not specified in the User type.

How do I check if the request body has type User, if not throw an error?

The route:

```
const edit = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        let data = req.body
        if (data instanceof User)
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(501).json({ error: err.message })
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' })
```

I can't find any help on the internet, so maybe someone could help me out?

So for example, if the payload of the post request is:

```
{
  "name": "Jack"
}
```

It should throw an error, because `name` is not a member of User.

How can I solve this? All help is appreciated!

---

**Updated now trying with classes:**

```
export class CUser {
    email: string
    creation_date: number
    first_name?: string
    last_name?: string
    payment_detals?: {
        iban: string
        last_updated: string
    }
    address?: {
        city: string
        street: string
        house_number: string
        postal_code: string
    }
    products?: string[]
}
```

The route

```
const edit = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let data = req.body
    console.log(data instanceof CUser)
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok' })
}
```

When the request.body is:

```
{
    "email": "mike@gmail.com",
    "creation_date": 849349388935
}
```

The `data instanceof CUser` will always result to false. Wait is it maybe because data is an object?..

Comment: You have to understand that TypeScript is compiled to normal JavaScript, which means all typehinting is stripped off. This means that the JavaScript that will be left, does not check for a class values to match with your input.

You really have to create custom validation to make sure the object properties match your input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I understand how it works now, but how can I tackle this problem? To deny unwanted fields?

Comment: You can use instanceof when you create a Class instead of a Type if im correct.

Then you just do if(!data instanceof User) { throw new Error('Not a User');}

Comment: But I see in a different comment that you cannot use Class, so that wont work as well...

Comment: The only solution then is very ugly...
You have to validate all fields in the object, e.g. for(let k in data), and check if it matches all properties in the Type...

Comment: Yeah I was about to say that. I've created a class User but instanceof always results to false... Damn..

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. I will try to create a snippet that works for u... Gimme a sec

Comment: Yeah I also created the for loop to check each key specific, but that would also not work. I could have done it the wrong way. Maybe you can show me a snippet of how you would do it, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok, I've played around with type a bit. A type isn't even compiled to Javascript to begin with. So you never can validate that with instanceof.

Comment: Could you maybe check my post, I've updated it. I'm now trying to do it with classes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, Im astounded by the fact that I cannot get this to work.
Apparently TypeScript strips away all properties that are not defined in a constructor, which completely breaks the instanceof validation.

Comment: Yeah it's not fun that I'm forced to use the constructor. But I've disabled it in the tsconfig.json with: "strictPropertyInitialization": false. Then I can skip the constructor. But it seems that if I want to use the `instanceof` method the data should be initialized as an object...

Comment: Maybe use an input lib, as mentioned here: https://blog.logrocket.com/dynamic-type-validation-in-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by writing a function which compares the request body with the types that I expect, and it works great! If there is something wrong with the fields or the required is wrong, the server will throw an error immediately. Here are some code snippets:

**The functions**

```
export type Schema = {
    fields: { [key: string]: string }
    required?: string[]
}

const required = (obj: any, required: string[]) => {
    for (let key of required) {
        if (obj[key] === undefined) return false
    }
    return true
}

export const validate = async (obj: any, model: Schema) => {
    if (model.required) {
        const status = required(obj, model.required)
        if (!status) return false
    }

    for (let key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (model.fields[key] === undefined) return false
        else if (typeof obj[key] !== model.fields[key]) return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Example type**

```
import { Schema } from './'

export type User = {
    email: string
    creation_date: number
    subscription: string
    first_name?: string
    last_name?: string
    payment_detals?: {
        iban: string
        last_updated: string
    }
    address?: {
        city: string
        street: string
        house_number: string
        postal_code: string
    }
    categories?: string[]
    products?: {
        ean: number
        category?: string
        notes?: string
    }[]
}

export const UserSchema: Schema = {
    fields: {
        email: 'string',
        subscription: 'string',
        first_name: 'string',
        last_name: 'string',
        payment_details: 'object',
        address: 'object',
        categories: 'object',
        products: 'object',
    },
    required: ['email']
}
```

**On the server**

```
let status = await validate(body, UserSchema)
if (!status) return res.status(422).json(Message.error.wrong_request_body)

// else continue
```

Comment: Why validate function is asynchronus?

Answer (score 2):

Types or interfaces that you define in Typescript are stripped when it's converted into Javascript, so you won't be able to able to check the type during runtime.

What you'll need to do is create a type-guard function that asserts true or false whether or not your request has those specific `User` properties.

For a good example see: [How to check the object type on runtime in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078205/how-to-check-the-object-type-on-runtime-in-typescript)

Comment: I'm now reading this: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard , and I do understand what you're explaining. But this only checks if a member is present, but it does not check the members which should not be present. So I can create a function that checks return obj.email !== undefined . But I want to check unwanted fields. If the user now sends a field `age` it will pass my code and save it into the database. I appreciate your answer. Maybe you have another idea? Something I might be missing. Please do correct me if my understandings are wrong.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't a super great way to do it. It's up to you how in-depth you want to make your type-guard. It's ugly but you could look through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined

Answer (score 1):

You can create a constructor or function in a typescript class , which will take the req.body and only pick the required keys from the object, assign to this member variable and return you a new instance of the User object.

Now you can apply the checks on User instance or also can create a validateObject method inside the User class

Comment: I'm not allowed to use classes, so I'll have to find a way to do this without classes I'm afraid.