# typescript array of objects with one property in each item

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-ads-api

I'm integrating Google Ads Rest API.I want to pass an array of type [UserIdentifier](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v10/UserIdentifier) to a function where each object should only have one item only because it is required by [this Google Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v10/customers.offlineUserDataJobs/addOperations)
for example:

```
f([{hashedEmail: "xxxxxx"}, {hashedPhoneNumber: "xxxxxx"}]) // OK
f([{hashedEmail: "xxxxxx", hashedPhoneNumber: "xxxxxx"}]) // Not Cool
```

[This example comes close](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/PTAEDECcHsFtQBYBckAcDOAuE6kEMBjAa2gDcBTSAMwBtoB3AOgLmD2AFYAGAZgHYOAJgAcANgCwAKCQBPVOVABVAHYBLaMoAq0AJLKkldOQJJ1ygDyKAfKAC8oABSLQ5AB4HlAE3Sg8ymaAA-I5EmEoAlHY2pNCqnqBhyuQUkJFuHt6ODqGgqspUlKA6kbbRsZ6RwToJoEkpANxSIBAwsGHIaFg4+MRklLQMzKzsHDwAnBwcACw8AIxSsvJF6Cpm5po29gDamgC6Lu7kXj5bqxraegaQRiZrG-vBVHg0RjVIkACu5I2SC3IKAGU8gBzGjkADS5Bk602yzOFiIUOgVFAGwOGR87y+QVqyUKYQA3gBfdFHTKaHF1fGon5SKgfZS3DSgKjrUnHUAAJWM0EgnnMuEgIIANL5-FYrA5oAAjABWYSBylBEKhMMiBKkoC1oGaLGU6GgYMYdGBDgJoBlstARPCPyJUjpZpt9R1YEoMGuiEo5AAhI7za4whxrbb-aBA6AOKKAmFRCGXc13byfAhvX7JEA) but I only want to use the keys that are mentioned in Google Ads API [UserIdentifier](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v10/UserIdentifier) type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61076348/280143

Comment: Don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the sort of structure you are looking for is a C-Style Union.  This means that you have an object that only has one property present out of all of the listed ones.  A helper generic type can easily be created to generate this structure:

```
type CUnion<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [K in keyof T]: { [_ in K]: T[K] } & { [K2 in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: undefined } }[keyof T];

// { ssn: boolean; webauth?: undefined } | { webauth: string; ssn?: undefined }
type UserID = CUnion<{
  ssn: boolean;
  webauth: string;
}>;

const asdf: UserID = {
  ssn: true,
};

const asdf2: UserID = {
  webauth: "hey"
};

// @ts-expect-error This correctly fails.
const asdf3: UserID = {
  ssn: true,
  webauth: "hey"
}
```

We need to make the other properties explicitly `undefined` and optional because TypeScript does not error when you specify properties in other parts of a union when they should not actually be there.  Anyways, here is your code adjusted to use this solution:

```
type CUnion<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = { [K in keyof T]: { [_ in K]: T[K] } & { [K2 in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: undefined } }[keyof T];

type UserIdentifier = CUnion<{
  hashedEmail: string,
  hashedPhoneNumber: string,
  mobileId: string,
  thirdPartyUserId: string,
  addressInfo: {
    hashedFirstName: string,
    hashedLastName: string,
    city: string,
    state: string,
    countryCode: string,
    postalCode: string,
    hashedStreetAddress: string
  }
}>;

declare const f: (identifiers: UserIdentifier[]) => void;

f([{ hashedEmail: "xxxxxx" }, { hashedPhoneNumber: "xxxxxx" }]) // OK -- correctly works!
f([{ hashedEmail: "xxxxxx", hashedPhoneNumber: "xxxxxx" }]) // Not Cool -- correctly errors!
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgqgOwJYHsEB4AqUIA9gQIAmAzlAEoQDGKATkeicLUggOYA0UArggNYIUAdwQA+UVAC8UAN5QA2gGkorKHwggUAMyiYAugC5ZCgPoqEURYd1K9UAL5QAZMaUAmc1ACiuKgBtuIgh0dU0dTC5FUT0AfiNeIK1WCCIHB3lQ7V09AG4AWAAoQtBIKDgSCFoASSCEYCQkyqlYRFQMGUKoKAALAEMSbpSvAFtepD8jJhZ2Dk6e-sGiAAVutAgAOW5hgCNKyeZWTjnhlG3xiBr96aOCruBupHol3tpQcsrLqCnD2duoXqIRFoEBIJCqCC0KCMHT+XT6AxSADFHkx1r1hhArj85nCFikADL9YBojFYmY4qBUJCgMk3LpdJi9Ai0370ykoXjMEAwFBBFkUsAoRl+Hl8r4Hcmw+YIogAZWYEAgwAAgoDgaDaXN7IV7KJ8kUCkF-C9oDQEEwoFojAAKJC1eqNWgkIzvar2hpISryPQASikEgAbig7frClprfI5PDFiMxhMoAAiXDJlMJhxcKN45arBAbLa7WhGJMp5Np+y+qAAekrUAA8soALQN9m0YFUYB+EBQIR0PgkACEYYjmZlsfGRZLpa40ZSKzWmx2e0Tk9wZYr1ag6xQwFgKBQfigTZbbY7XcqtDoA8KQA)