# How to declare a record type which has certain keys mapping to values, and the rest undefined

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have the following code:

```
const myObj = {
    "hello": "world";
} as const;

const anyString: string = "Hi"
if (myObj[anyString]) { // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ readonly hello: "world"; }'.
    console.log('Property exists!', anyString)
}
```

The error it produces, it produces seems misguided as the type definition of `myObj` should be something like:

```
interface TMyObj {
  [specificKeys: "hello"]: "world",
  [otherKeys: string]: undefined
}
```

But it produces the error because it does not trust me on the `[otherKeys: string]: undefined` part, thinking that I could add anything to it.

However, that case is effectively guarded against, because doing so is a type-error itself:

```
myObj.bar = "other value" // Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ readonly hello: "world"; }
```

Is there a way I can write type safe code in this case without casting `anyString` to be a key of `myObj`? Because it's not guaranteed to be.

This seems like something that `as const` should handle tbh.

Comment: I don't know if there had been any advances in the language but this might be your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined It's not supported but you can do stuff with object literals.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why are expecting `myObj` to have a `string` index signature with  a value of `undefined`. This would essentially allow accessing any property of any object without leading to a compile time error. The TypeScript developers decided that trying to access a property which an object *can't* have will lead to an error.

What you probably want to do instead is to use the `in` operator. `in` will allow any string/number/symbol value.

```
if (anyString in myObj) {
    console.log('Property exists!', anyString)
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeBYAKBmJgCIALAUwBtqRSAuMgdxACdqATUwgXxgCGEGKEhQA3IUKjogsAgDKUNgEswAcybRVGrGQASKngRUAzGAAoB8pTvUw18ZOgCUuQiRHgIIapQB0dOoWAOQACmwgAA6UbFAIMJQAHirQEACEIQA0corKauoufEA)