# Get a partial Object from other Object using a Type?

Tags: typescript

I hope the topic is not too confusing, but I don't know how to say it better.
Let's say I have an object like this in Typescript:

```
type TypeA = {a : number, b: number, c : {d: number, e: number}}
const ObjA = {a: 1, b: 2, c : {d : 3, e: 4}}
```

Now I have a second Type which is always a part of `TypeA`:

```
type TypeB = {a: number, c: {e: number}}
```

how would I generate an `ObjB` from `ObjA` but instead of all the information in the object it should only have these from `TypeB`.

Is there a quick and easy way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to restrict TypeScript object to contain only properties defined by its class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined)

Comment: I do have an idea, but it will make the code really complex and will require a function invocation that will loop through the keys and remove them, but I don't recommend doing something like that so just manually create it

Comment: So you want `function runtimeDeepPick` ?

Comment: So are you asking for a solution in *types*, or a solution at *runtime*, or *both*?

Comment: both would be interesting! if there is a solution