# How to define a generic helper that properly appends variably partially typed objects to an array field?

Tags: typescript

Here's the minimal example code I am playing with:

```js
function isPropArray<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): obj is T & { [P in K]: any[] } {
    return Array.isArray(obj[key]);
}

function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, key: K): Required<T>[K]; 
function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U>(
    obj: T, key: K,
    ...elements: NonNullable<T[K]> extends U[] ? U[] : never): Required<T>[K];
function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U>(
    obj: T, key: K, ...elements: NonNullable<T[K]> extends U[] ? U[] : never) {
    if (!isPropArray(obj,key)) {
      obj[key] = [...elements] as T[K];
    } else {
      obj[key].push(...elements);
    }
    return obj[key];
}

type Thing = { a?: { x?: number }[] };
const x:Thing = {};
appendToArrayAndReturn(x, 'a', { x: 1 });
```

Here the error is `Argument of type '[{ x: number; y: boolean; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`.

The implementation is sufficient to achieve the goal but for this type of example, where the type `{ x?: number }[]` is improperly being matched against a provided `{ x: number }[]`. Naturally it's impossible to send in a partial object, so the `| undefined` is the spanner in the works here.

I tried tweaking the signature to `extends (Required<U>[]) ?`... but that unfortunately did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just switching the order of `NonNullable<T[K]> extends U[]` to `U[] extends NonNullable<T[K]>` gets rid of the error:

```
function isPropArray<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): obj is T & { [P in K]: any[] } {
    return Array.isArray(obj[key]);
}

function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, key: K): Required<T>[K]; 
function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U>(
    obj: T, key: K,
    ...elements: U[] extends NonNullable<T[K]> ? U[] : never ): Required<T>[K];
function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T, U>(
    obj: T, key: K, ...elements: U[] extends NonNullable<T[K]> ? U[] : never) {
    if (!isPropArray(obj,key)) {
      obj[key] = [...elements] as T[K];
    } else {
      obj[key].push(...elements);
    }
    return obj[key];
}

type Thing = { a?: { x?: number }[] };
const x:Thing = {};
appendToArrayAndReturn(x, 'a', { x: 1 });
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgBQE5wA4EEMYCGAngDwAqANIgNKICmAHlPWACYqIDW9xcwicgD4AFHABGAKwBcg6j2KyaASlkTJyTuUQAyRAG9EAbTTIkNALqzCYYkYuIAvgYBQid4gz0oIDEnxExAB0qAEkYlJGChbKANwuji4uoJCwCIiE2NisbORwYcS47ABK3r5gFAzMOZzq9NDUdEws7JwK-IKibh7qslTcvEqqiKUAjiAwXmwUQkaWsYjJ4NDwSJnZ7HkFRWylPn6VzTWIdQ20VS0cA3wC-QCqXR4nUn3yg7SU3e5BP-QANvQALasKAoWR3ewXY4AOQQ0JAfz+hHEAIocwsQkQAH5EBCHLIwPQAG70DCIYZjCZTGbo+IpFbpdY5LYEEg7PblQ7VVrPST1KCNKE89q3agPERfXmva5Kag-IL-IEgsG4yFHHmwsDwxHI1HkdGYnF4xAE4mk5SuJ4wAQiACEqEwOAKEUklAUygt+kl7nUUV4DgAvMZ5YrgWBQQ5CFpaZLnP8UPRLU9eX7iBYgtgQCgABYiEMAsOguKxyVefZIX3ReKJFxQYjZQTZmBgADmiCDhkIWNkhkY3cQYBAgPEpKckMc8QgCBQUEQjGk5CbrfbBgnLiZm3yrMKJTKfhEjGoAHJCEfqL3ZABGJxxIA)

---

Reason:

```
type test<X,Y> = X extends Y ? true : false 

type A = {x?: number}
type B = {x: number}

type test1 = test<A,B> // false
type test2 = test<B,A> // true
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMEM7ADwA0A0BNAfFAvFZUEAHrAHYAmcU6UA-DAE4Cu0AXFAGYCGANnNACgBoSFACCuKAG8itdqSYBbAEYQGAX2HhoAIUkz5S1RqEjosBAEZJFpGNQ7sAeiede-LaNsAmG-CQ6qGLOrsDMEEA)

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately the semantics of this are identical to if I try `extends Partial<U>[] ` (as opposed to what i tried earlier, with `extends Required<U>[] `) in there. What this does is makes it no longer error, but now I can shove anything else I want in there such as `{ x: 1, z: 2, y: 3 }` and it won't be type checked. Because these then become compatible. I need some way to force it to check the input e.g.  `[{ x: 1 }]` against the type `{ x?: number }[]` upconverted to `{ x: number }[]` (aka. `Required<U>[]`) so the comparison will be appropriate.

Comment: or possibly something shaped like `(T[K] extends (infer R)[] ? R : never) extends U ? Required<U>[] : never`... testing...

Comment: @StevenLu Yeah that's a classic Typescript flaw - it generally allows extra properties. You can see here for a discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined. You can generally assign extra properties to things unless declaring an object literal. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAPAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAXwG4AoAYwHtMBnYLG4ORVDARgBooQ1O5anUZQAhhjbNWZIA). I personally wouldn't worry about it. Sometimes you just need to accept JS is dynamically typed.

Comment: Could you comment on my answer I posted? Still experimenting, so not confident it is bulletproof yet.

Comment: @StevenLu nice, just FYI that'll only catch extra properties if passing object literals. It won't work if the parameter is a variable. ie. `const y = {x:1, y:1}; appendToArrayAndReturn(x, 'a', y);` will give no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it working via:

```js
  function appendToArrayAndReturn<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, ...elements: NonNullable<T[K]> extends (infer R)[] ? R[] : never): Required<T>[K] {
    if (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = [...elements] as T[K];
    } else {
      (obj[key] as any[]).push(...elements);
    }
    return obj[key];
  }
```

I was able to drop the type guard I was using as well as the overloads!

If someone out there could explain elegantly why this is the way to go, or if I'm still doing something stupid, that would be great.

This provides far superior error messages compared to before as well, since instead of complaining about not being able to assign some object to `never`, which doesnt explain anything, it shows a more typical error like `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'z' does not exist in type '{ req: number; opt?: number | undefined; }'.`

Comment: I went in one day from not knowing how to use `infer` and being scared to use it to considering it the best thing since sliced bread. Change my mind. Haha.