# Typescript is not catching errors when returning object property which doesn't exist on the return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript is not showing error when returning an object with properties which doesn't exist on the return type.

```
type TResponse = Partial<{
    name: string
}>
 
type TTemplate = (n: number) => TResponse;
 
const getTemplate: TTemplate = (n) => {
  if (n > 5) {
    return {
      name: 'ddd'
    }
  }
 
  return {
    age: 18
  }
}
```

The `getTemplate` function should return `TResponse` which is type of object with `name` property. But when returning `age` property conditionally, it is not a typescript error, while I was expecting to get an error as I'm returning a property which doesn't satisfy the `TTemplate`.

Note: The typescript will show it as an error in these conditions,

1. If I assign the return object with a variable and return it

```
const getTemplate1: TTemplate = (n) => {
 if (n > 5) {
   return {
     name: 'ddd'
   }
 }

 const result = {
   age: 18
 }

 return result;
}
```

2. If the arguments and returns types are specified separately instead of giving a function type.

```
const getTemplate2 = (n: number): TResponse => {
  if (n > 5) {
    return {
      name: 'ddd'
    }
  }
 
  return {
    age: 18
  }
}
```

I don't understand how the first snippet is different from these working snippets, as it's common to give a function type to functions.

[Typescript demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=46&ssc=5&pln=36&pc=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgShAzmA9gO0dAvFACgQwCdgBLfAGwB4BvAKCgajXwFsIAuKRYQktAc1oBfAHz1aoSLBgQWYcvmDYoACjSc0AVxYAjCIQCUULCNgJk6TAG5xUWgGNLwKPwjAZchUs4wP8xcpqRiZQdAwkAGaqaFCmAKxGYYyEbpqEMUmMTKwcUADkACZFefSMQqXldgwpwGkZpQz4rpwAjAAcFcK0tAD0PVAA6iiEANZ8-FAoYKToUC29-Y4Yzq7usv5KLT5%20XoFowaZ0fYyR0bFQCaELWVA1dVfHN9lsnIXF11nlj1CVH1BL3FuSE05GcOCO-SyTVy7T%205T%20d3SQMQIOANmO8OOQ1G40m0xIswATNcASs3DsAoTjNENNo9IYfOZUBhsIc-qc1OdLhCboj6t8sswXvkigUSgKfnDxN8%20Q9IYxoa0Ot8vv0hEA)

Comment: just an assumption, I think it is related to TTemplate that returns TResponse, and TResponse returns a Partial object, so the second return "{age:18}" is valid, it recognizes it as a partial object but when you assign it to a const it becomes an object type and not a partial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to restrict TypeScript object to contain only properties defined by its class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined)